# Python 2.7 Multiprocessing Manager IOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, sockets, selenium-webdriver

I have a script where I am making multiple HTTP requests to various websites to extract data.  The requests are being made through Python's Selenium Webdriver.  For whatever reason, I need to declare the following at the top of my script to avoid getting the following exception: IOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable.

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(None)
```

I have researched many places online and cannot come to the conclusion why this is needed (other than perhaps a bug in Python).  This solves my initial issue, however when I tried to perform a download with Selenium, I get a type error, stating a float value is required for timeout (i.e - not None).

Can anyone tell me what exactly is happening here?  I tried to set the default timeout before downloading with Selenium but this does not work due to the intricacies of the script architecture.

Comment: So, I did decide to re-design the architecture of the software to use many locks instead of locking within a basemanager shared object.  I believe this to have solved my problem.